# rvest & reading HTML files from local directory

Tags: html, r, regex, rvest

I have *many* HTML files stored in a local directory. Ideally, I'd like to use rvest to extract the table nodes, make some flavor of dataframe, and export the files as .txt files. I'm not sure how to properly import the HTML files into a structure rvest can handle.

What I've attempted so far:

```
# Load libraries
library(tm)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

# Set file path
folder <- 'path to directory'
extension <- '.html'

# Read files to list 
htmls <- lapply(X=html,
                FUN=function(file){
                  .con <- file(description=paste(folder, file, sep='/'))
                  .html <- readLines(.con)
                  close(.con)
                  names(.html)  <- file
                  .html
                })
```

And then, painfully, using regex + lapply/sapply to loop through the files and extract the tables.

Advice on a more efficient workflow and/or how to best optimize rvest?

Comment: Did you try just using `read_html()` with the path to the local file?

Comment: For a single HTML file? Yes. Works well. I have 7,000+ files stored in a local directory. I'm looking to pull them all in, which is why I've tried writing them to a list.

Comment: I’m saying use read_html inside your lapply rather than this readLines stuff. Use list.files() to pass in a vector of all the file names.

Comment: Take a look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/furrr/index.html. It's relatively new and aligns with the "tidyverse". There are also parallel ways to use base *apply methods. @MrFlick is spot on that you should stick with HTML/XML ops and parallelism will likely speed things up dramatically.

Comment: You can also do what your doing (read contents into memory) and still use read_html().